# It is possible to load babel with a default language if none is specified in the class?

Tags: babel, documentclass-writing

I would like to write a class that loads the package `babel` with a default language but that this language could be overridden by a language specified in the class options. MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2015/09/22 v0 testclass]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{babel}
%% or
%% \RequirePackage[english]{babel}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper, english]{test}
%% or 
%% \documentclass{test}

\begin{document}
\Huge We are typing in \languagename. 
\end{document}
```

As written, `babel` is loaded (as expected) with english. But if I omit `english` in the option, I have an error (logically) from babel.

The problem is that if I use `\RequirePackage[english]{babel}` in the class I can't override it --- for example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2015/09/22 v0 testclass]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper, spanish]{test}
\begin{document}
\Huge We are typing in \languagename. 
\end{document}
```

...is still printing out "english".

Is there a general way to solve this generically, or I have the only option to use `\DeclareOption` each language that I am interested in and create a big `\if` loading `babel` in different ways?

To explain better --- I know how to provide with `\DeclareOption` a way to explicitily set babel defaults, like in [jon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268999/38080). But suppose I want that the class' users could do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, whatever]{test}  %% babel default to english
```

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper, whatever, turkish, serbian, italian]{test}
%% ...and now babel is called with [turkish, serbian, italian] options
```

The way I have it now is requiring the package `babel` with no option and letting it fail if the user do not specify at least a language on the class options... and documenting it. But it would be nice to have a default...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but what about something like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{langtest.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{langtest}[2015/09/22 v0 testclass]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\DeclareOption{spanish}{\PassOptionsToPackage{english,main=spanish}{babel}}
\DeclareOption{english}{\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}}
\ExecuteOptions{english} % set default value as "english"


\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{babel}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman, spanish]{langtest}
\begin{document}
\Huge We are typing in \languagename.
\end{document}
```

In my `emacs` output buffer, I see:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))                 
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty                 
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf        
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf       
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))              
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)      
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)      
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.ldf)      
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.ldf)))
```

Comment: In fact, while we're creating shortcuts and so on, I might be inclined to name my options `span` and `eng`, and then use them in the class options....

Comment: Yes, this is what I mentioned at the end of my question --- thanks anyway for a clean way to do it. The problem is that I should do that for each and everyone of the languages I expect the class users can choose to use, and every combination of...  I'll try to explain better in the questoon.

Comment: Rmano -- You want it to pick `english` if nothing is said, or only the languages given in the class options? Why not create an option called `overridelang` and explain in the docs that if you want to override the `english` setting, you must use `overridelang` and specify the languages the user wants to use? I.e., `\documentclass[overridelangs, turkish, greek, spanish]{myclass}`. Then you simply need one if-statement: either `babel+english` or `babel+nothing`.

Comment: yes, this is a good idea. Not so "clean" as I'd like, but better than letting `babel` bailing out in error. It's a pity that a `try... catch` thing is not possible in TeX!

Comment: Rmano -- Yeah, not very clean, I know.  `babel` is a hard thing to wrap, and TeX error handling is pretty rigid....

Answer (score 0):

I landed here and the solution for my problem was this:

The last language specified in the `RequirePackage` command for `babel` is the default. With this command it will load spanish and english and have english as the default:

```
\RequirePackage[spanish,english]{babel}
```